# Unable to search in gedit

Tags: 16.04, gedit

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo X1 carbon 5th gen laptop. My system is fully up to date and the version of `gedit` is `3.18.3`. From last week onwards I am unable to perform a search on `gedit`. When <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>f</kbd> is pressed the search field becomes available on top right corner and upon pressing the first letter of the word for searching, the search field disappears leaving unable to search in `gedit` How to fix this?

Comment: Opening `gedit` via terminal may print some error message.

Comment: @g_p no error is printed in the terminal

Comment: Reproducing such problem is not possible. Easiest solution can be purging  and reinstalling gedit . However you can wait for other to answer.

Comment: after over a year, I can confirm this bug. Gnome is basically malware.

Comment: @g_p it prints error if opened with sudo rights . See this question .https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235728/saving-file-on-gedit-prints-a-warning-in-terminal

Answer (score 1):

I have been fighting with the newer version of gedit 3.18.3 for some time now. Other forum answers have been to revert to version 3.10. My solution has been to use Notepadqq:

```
Applications->System Tools->Software
or
Show Applications -> Software
```

Open the Software app and search for Notepadqq

To completely remove gedit go to terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge gedit
```

Now that you have an application that solves your immediate problem you can take your time and find a text editor which may even be better. Honestly, however, don't spend more time with gedit. The online documentation is obsolete. Also there appears to be a different GUI depending on which OS you are using, so everyone says something different. Personally I am using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and my gedit version is pretty much usless unless you just want to type text and nothing else.

Once you have decided on your final text editor. You need to open Files (Nautilus), right click any .txt file, select properties, then "open with" and select your new default text editor.

Comment: This won't work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, Gedit 3.28.1, and what ever the root cause was it also affected filling forms in webpages when using Firefox, e.g. for GitHub login. (If a field was entered by pressing Tab key, only one character could be fed to the field, because after every keystroke the text in the field was selected, thus being overwritten on next keystroke. This is what was actually happening in Gedit search box too.)

Gedit outputted the following when started from shell:

```
** (gedit:8601): WARNING **: 10:21:17.835: (gedit/gedit-view-frame.c:121):get_iter_at_start_mark: code should not be reached
```

Anyway, for me this was resolved by disabling the shortcut "Toggle maximization state" from **System Settings > Keyboard, Shortcuts-tab > Windows**, which has been "super" i.e. Windows key.